# How can I get sublime text 3 to auto adjust paths in my imported paths, for ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, ide, sublimetext3

I have seen other IDEs that can watch your project structure, and if you move a file from one folder to another, all references or imports to that file will be auto adjusted in all files that reference that file.

I can't seem to find information anywhere so far for how to implement this feature or if there's a package out there that handles this.

I would appreciate any suggestions from anyone that has got it to work. My project is in React, so basically it's to update all the component imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a new plugin called [JavaScript Enhancements](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/JavaScriptEnhancements), that you can find on [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaScript%20Enhancements). It uses [Flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow) (javascript static type checker from Facebook) under the hood.

It offers **smart javascript autocomplete**, **real-time errors**, **code refactoring** and also a lot of features about creating, developing and managing javascript projects.

In your case you could use https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/JavaScriptEnhancements/wiki/Code-Refactoring#safe-move

An introduction to this plugin could be found in this css-tricks.com article: [Turn Sublime Text 3 into a JavaScript IDE](https://css-tricks.com/turn-sublime-text-3-into-a-javascript-ide/)